# How to bind a key sequence in Ruby Tk?

Tags: ruby, events, sequence, tk-toolkit

I am tring to bind the key sequence `Control_L` + `Up` in a Tk widget in Ruby. More explicitely, I want a proc to run when "Control_Left" and "Arrow-Up" are pressed together.

Untill now I have not been successful, I tried many combinations looking at TclTk, Python and Perl docs but I could not find the way out.

It should be something similar to

```
 widget.bind("Control_L Up", proc {
  puts "-----> sequence ok  "  
 })
```

p.s. One by one the two events `Control_L` and `Up` are correcly catched.

Comment: I found that the sequence `bind . <Control-Key-Up> { puts "hello" }` makes it in `wish` shell. Unfortunately coping the same key sequence in Ruby does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, to whoever may need it in future, this is the working snippet

```
require 'tk'
root = TkRoot.new()
root.minsize [400, 300]
root.geometry "+200+200"
root.bind('Control-Key-Up', proc { puts "presssed Control + Up"; } )
Tk.mainloop()
```

Observe that (1) it works even in form `'Control Key Up'` as stated in TclTk docs. But it does not work if you write it as `'<Control-Key-Up>'`, which is the default Tk syntax.

Comment: Since, as you say, your own answer works, please accept it.